# Animations in Angular

Tags: jquery, html, css, angular, animation

I am using angular-5 in my project. There are lots of animations in pages. Most simplified method of adding and removing some classes to DOM elements is using jQuery. I also uses many methods of jQuery like `animate()` and others. But most of time, it is suggested that jQuery should not be used in Angular. Is there any way to avoid using jQuery and still make a responsive animated website. I also want to mention that my site is only static site which doesn't have any DB or backend. All suggestions are welcome.

Thank you

Comment: there's a whole section about angular animations at their site. https://angular.io/guide/animations

Answer (score 1):

Angular comes with `animation module`.

Angular animations are built on top of the standard [Web Animations API](https://w3c.github.io/web-animations/) and run natively on [browsers that support it.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=web-animation)

The official documentation is here: https://angular.io/guide/animations

Here are quick examples put together by angular team on stackblitz: https://jnmormjeloo.angular.stackblitz.io